# Django custom user models in 1.8

Tags: python, django, authentication

I'd like to create a project for finding mentor.
In planning i thought, that it would be nice to separate two models on registration users: for students (those, who wants to find mentor) and mentors. 
Built-in django user model isn't like that. I plan to add more fields, also several fields can be the same: in students and in mentors.

Can you give me live example of customing model? Would be nice, if you have smth in git or other code sharing.
Shoudl I inherit mentor model from students, because it can have same fields: email, name, surname, etc?

What additional code should i write for working custom model? I read docs and found unknown for me - managers. Should i also customize managers?

If i get success in custom model what problems can i meet in future for auth,registration, changing passwords for this custom model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website has two intended users, so there is no problem with creating two user models. Just make sure to inherit them from user model

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Student(User):

     ...

class Mentor(User):

     ...
```

Answer (score 4):

Creating 2 separate models is not recommended here. You will need to have separate login process and be careful to avoid problems with sharing pk between users in separate tables. Also I'm pretty sure that django won't allow that.

Better choice is to make 2 profile models, as described in [Extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). In one of profiles you will store specific data for student and in other specific data for mentors.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't re-invent the wheel, except you really want to learn and practice core features of Django. Just add some add-on library like [userena](https://django-userena.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which "supplies you with signup, signin, account editing, privacy settings and private messaging". In general userena gives an additional UserenaBaseProfile model which is connected to built-in User model. So you can just inherit this model for the Student and for the Mentor:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile

class CustomProfile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True)
    common_field_for_all_children = models.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Student(CustomProfile):
    something_student_related = models.IntegerField()

class Mentor(CustomProfile):
    something_mentor_related = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```